# Adding External libraries to QT 5.1.1 project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, assimp

I am trying to include the assimp library (http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_doc.html) for importing assets into my QT project.

I managed to include it in VS2012 but not in QT.

The import wizard gives me this code:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/assimp--3.0.1270-sdk/lib/assimp_debug-dll_win32/ -lassimp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/assimp--3.0.1270-sdk/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/assimp--3.0.1270-sdk/include

win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/assimp--3.0.1270-sdk/lib/assimp_debug-dll_win32/assimp.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/assimp--3.0.1270-sdk/lib/assimp_debug-dll_win32/libassimp.a
```

When i build the code it throws this error
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()'

If i understand it right:

```
QT / VS2012
INCLUDEPATH =Include directories
LIBS = Library directories
PRE_TARGETDEPS=Additional dependancies
```

Do i have to manualy add the location off the .dll file into .pro or what am i missing?

Comment: Do you have a dll file?

Comment: I do have the dll file, i put it in the debug folder of my qt project. VS2012 gives me an error if the file is missing (it works when its in the debug folder), but QT doesnt give me that error.